# Python Error- TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'Chain' and 'Chain'

Tags: python, qgis, chain

When trying to work with Python plugin "Hotspot Analaysis" I see "Python Error"
This is what loads when looking at the complete error message:

```
2022-09-09T10:27:29     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sgreen94/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/HotspotAnalysis/hotspot_analysis.py", line 532, in 
  self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda: self.load_comboBox())
  File "/Users/sgreen94/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/HotspotAnalysis/hotspot_analysis.py", line 473, in load_comboBox
  thresh = pysal.lib.weights.user.min_threshold_dist_from_shapefile(path)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/pysal/lib/weights/user.py", line 92, in min_threshold_dist_from_shapefile
  return min_threshold_distance(points, p)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/pysal/lib/weights/util.py", line 1116, in min_threshold_distance
  kd = KDTree(data)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/scipy/spatial/kdtree.py", line 239, in __init__
  self.maxes = np.amax(self.data,axis=0)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2505, in amax
  initial=initial)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 86, in _wrapreduction
  return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
 TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'Chain' and 'Chain'
```

Any idea what may causing this?

Comment: You need to post a [mre]

Comment: What does "*trying to work with Python plugin "Hotspot Analaysis"*" mean? Please post your code.

Comment: @cristiFati Hotspot Analysis is an experimental plugin: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/HotspotAnalysis/